# colors are not accurate after screen replacement

Tags: laptop, display, asus-laptop, laptop-repair, toshiba-laptop

I have replaced my broken screen with another laptop brand screen both are 40 pin and 15.6" ([Acer TravelMate 5742](https://icecat.biz/en-my/p/acer/lx.tz903.182/travelmate-notebooks-5742-382g32mnss-8530690.html) screen used on [Toshiba c50 a539](https://yaoota.com/en-eg/product/toshiba-satellite-c50-a539-price-from-digital-city-egypt)), everything working correctly but the colors are not accurate a little bit, tried color calibration but failed.

I am wondering if I can change the main screen circuit part with the new one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you can find the screen you can likely replace it.  This is source of color issues.

Comment: @John hey, I didn't understand your point, can you explain, please?

Comment: I am wondering if I can change the main screen panel with the new one.  ..... If you can find a new correct panel then you should be able to replace it

Comment: @john the old screen still functioning but has only a few dotes on it, so it's possible to replace its pannel with the other one?

Comment: If you can find a new and proper screen then you (or a local shop) should be able to replace it.

Comment: What do you mean by "its panel"?

Comment: @gronostaj The circuit part of the LCD  when the 40 pin is placed( I am not sure if its correct , its behind the DO NOT TOUCH text)

Comment: That's the LCD driver. It's unlikely to help.